# Can't use method in div onclick

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, navigation

I have one angular sample, below is my **app.component.ts** file:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Core Helper';
  
  constructor(private router: Router) { 
    // this.router = Router;
  }

  navigate() {
      this.router.navigate(["docs"]);
  }
  }
```

> app.component.html

```html
<div id="releasenotes" onclick="navigate()">Release Notes</div>
```

When i call this method it throws below error:

```js
dashboard:27 Uncaught ReferenceError: navigate is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (dashboard:27)
```

I dont know how to solve this i have tried like below

```js
 document.getElementById('releasenotes').addEventListener("click", this.navigate);
```

In this case, router got undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular syntax for the click handler is written as **(click)="methodName()"**

Change the app.component.html code from

```
<div id="releasenotes" onclick="navigate()">Release Notes</div>
```

to

```
<div id="releasenotes" (click)="navigate()">Release Notes</div>
```

Comment: thanks brother...working fine but why onclick is not working